# How to ignore import file from Global import in Robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have imported `Resource` from the submodule and then I need to rewrite some data in the file but it doesn't work because it calling the global file import

Example:

```sh
# submodule/imports/web_global.robot
*** Settings ***
Variables   ${CURDIR}/../test_data/products_data.yaml
${products_data}: global

# imports/web_local.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource    ${CURDIR}/../submodule/imports/web_global.robot
Variables   ${CURDIR}/../test_data/products_data.yaml
${products_data}: local

# testcases/web/test_file.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource        ${CURDIR}/../../imports/web_local.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Log To Console    ${products_data}
```

I got the last result is `global`. How to get the last result to `local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I painstakingly re-created your entire, convoluted chain.

The semantic answer to your question:  when there is a naming conflict, Robot takes the first one (ignores your 2nd definition of the like-named variable `products_data`).

You can read about it in the [RF User Guide, section on variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#taking-variable-files-into-use)

Here is the relevant paragraph:

> All variables from a variable file are available in the test data file that imports it. If several variable files are imported and they contain a variable with the same name, the one in the earliest imported file is taken into use. Additionally, variables created in Variable tables and set from the command line override variables from variable files.

Simplest solution:  in imports/web_local.robot, remove the Resource which you do not want:

```
*** Settings ***
#Resource    ${CURDIR}/../submodule/imports/web_global.robot
Variables   ${CURDIR}/test_data/products_data.yaml
```

Now your variable from imports/test_data/products_data.yaml is used.

Good luck untangling!  I recommend re-thinking your structure.

Answer (score 1):

You might be confusing the yaml method of supplying variables with the ${} "usual way".  As given, your "${var}: " causes a syntax error because it is an illegal variable name (cannot end with a colon).

You do not show your products_data.yaml (please supply all code), but I am guessing that your ${products_data}:  should be expressed as

```
VAR: value

PRODUCTS_DATA:   global
```

It is a confusing question and I am struggling to grasp it.

Here is my attempt to re-create your question, but I could not re-produce the full sense of your question.

```
*** Settings ***
Variables   ${CURDIR}/test_data/products_data.yaml

*** Variables ***
${products_data}   local

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Log To Console   Value of products_data is ${products_data}\n
```

and the result:

```
==============================================================================
SOExample                                                                     
==============================================================================
Example                                                               Value of products_data is local

Example                                                               | PASS |
```